# retrieving elements from a jagged array after entering as runtime inputs

Tags: java, jagged-arrays

I'm trying to print jagged array elements after entering during run-time. But upon printing, I'm unable to do so as it's printing zeros. Can someone please help me in correcting this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import static java.lang.System.in;

class JaggedArrayDemo2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {   Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("\nEnter the number of rows for the jagged array:\t");
        int row_length = input.nextInt();
        int column_length;
        int r, c;
        int[][] jar = new int[row_length][];

        out.println("\nEnter the number of columns for each row:");
        for (r=0; r<row_length ; r++)
        {   out.print("jar["+r+"]  =  ");
            column_length = input.nextInt();    
            jar[r] = new int[column_length];
        }

        out.println("\nEnter the individual elements:");
        for(r = 0; r<jar.length; r++)
        {   for(c = 0;  c < jar[r].length; c++)
            {   out.print("jar["+r+"]["+c+"]  =  ");
                input.nextInt();    }
        }

        out.println("\nThe resultant jagged array is:");
        for(r = 0; r<jar.length; r++)
        {   for(c = 0;  c < jar[r].length; c++)
            {out.print(jar[r][c]+"\t");}
            out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Actual result, the prompt for storing in individual array elements is working okay, but without any changes in for loop for reading, it is giving the result as 0s.

```
D:\JavaEx\ARRAYS>java JaggedArrayDemo2

Enter the number of rows for the jagged array:  3

Enter the number of columns for each row:
jar[0]  =  4
jar[1]  =  2
jar[2]  =  3

Enter the individual elements:
jar[0][0]  =  1
jar[0][1]  =  2
jar[0][2]  =  3
jar[0][3]  =  4
jar[1][0]  =  5
jar[1][1]  =  6
jar[2][0]  =  7
jar[2][1]  =  8
jar[2][2]  =  9

The resultant jagged array is:
0       0       0       0
0       0
0       0       0
```

Expected result, only for printing:

```
The resultant jagged array is:
1       2       3       4
5       6
7       8       9
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase, I tried swapping jar.length and row_length but it really didn't matter as they are obviously equal, it's just that I couldn't find the distinguishing mark.

Comment: @NicoHaase it was embarrassing though, mixing up with other language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your 2nd for loop, replace

```
input.nextInt();        //Only Accepting the value. Not storing it.
```

with

```
jar[r][c] = input.nextInt();  //Accepting and storing the value.
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about actually **storing** the values?

```
    out.println("\nEnter the individual elements:");
    for(r = 0; r<jar.length; r++)
    {   for(c = 0;  c < jar[r].length; c++)
        {   out.print("jar["+r+"]["+c+"]  =  ");
            input.nextInt();    }
    }
```

...this code does only ask the user for input, but it does not do anything with that input. Try the following code which stores the inputted number in the `jar` array:

```
    out.println("\nEnter the individual elements:");
    for(r = 0; r<jar.length; r++)
    {   for(c = 0;  c < jar[r].length; c++)
        {   out.print("jar["+r+"]["+c+"]  =  ");
            jar[r][c] = input.nextInt();    }
    }
```

Comment: Just missed, my bad, I just started comparing with 2d array exercise, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Following will work. In your code, you are not storing input values in array.

Replace `input.nextInt()` in second `for` loop with `jar[r][c] = input.nextInt()`

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.in;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class JaggedArrayDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("\nEnter the number of rows for the jagged array:\t");
        int row_length = input.nextInt();
        int column_length;
        int r, c;
        int[][] jar = new int[row_length][];

        out.println("\nEnter the number of columns for each row:");
        for (r = 0; r < row_length; r++) {
            out.print("jar[" + r + "]  =  ");
            column_length = input.nextInt();
            jar[r] = new int[column_length];
        }

        out.println("\nEnter the individual elements:");
        for (r = 0; r < jar.length; r++) {
            for (c = 0; c < jar[r].length; c++) {
                out.print("jar[" + r + "][" + c + "]  =  ");
                jar[r][c] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

        out.println("\nThe resultant jagged array is:");
        for (r = 0; r < jar.length; r++) {
            for (c = 0; c < jar[r].length; c++) {
                out.print(jar[r][c] + "\t");
            }
            out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store input inside 2-D array named **jar**

Change

**input.nextInt();**

to

**jar [r][c] = input.nextInt();**

Here is the updated code snippet

```
out.println("\nEnter the individual elements:");
    for (r = 0; r < jar.length; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < jar[r].length; c++) {
            out.print("jar[" + r + "][" + c + "]  =  ");
            jar [r][c] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

Click here to view in the picture
[updated code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hcSa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Exact Solution :

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.lang.System.in;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class JaggedArrayDemo2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(in);
        out.print("\nEnter the number of rows for the jagged array:\t");
        int row_length = input.nextInt();
        int column_length;
        int r, c;
        int[][] jar = new int[row_length][];

        out.println("\nEnter the number of columns for each row:");
        for (r = 0; r < row_length; r++) {
            out.print("jar[" + r + "]  =  ");
            column_length = input.nextInt();
            jar[r] = new int[column_length];
        }

        out.println("\nEnter the individual elements:");
        for (r = 0; r < jar.length; r++) {
            for (c = 0; c < jar[r].length; c++) {
                out.print("jar[" + r + "][" + c + "]  =  ");
                jar[r][c] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }

        out.println("\nThe resultant jagged array is:");
        for (r = 0; r < jar.length; r++) {
            for (c = 0; c < jar[r].length; c++) {
                out.print(jar[r][c] + "\t");
            }
            out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```